# why is only one thread gets executed and other is not

Tags: python, python-multithreading

```
import threading,time

def auto2():

    while 1:
        print ("hello master")
        time.sleep(2)

def auto1():

     while 1:
         print "hello"
         time.sleep(3)

x=threading.Thread(target=auto1(),args=())

y=threading.Thread(target=auto2(),args=())

x.start()

y.start()
```

Comment: To be clear for everybody, please describe your expected behaviour and your actual behaviour, even if the code is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading, time
def auto2():
    while 1:
        print("hello master")
        time.sleep(2)
def auto1():
    while 1:
        print ("hello")
        time.sleep(3)
x = threading.Thread(target=auto1)
y = threading.Thread(target=auto2)
x.start()
y.start()
```

target=auto1() - > target=auto1

Comment: is arg necessary and when is that used?